# How to store credentials for multiple Github accounts (not individual repos) using libsecret

Tags: linux, ubuntu, git, github, version-control

I'm trying to use 2 github accounts on Ubuntu 18.04. I'm also using personal-access-tokens (PAT). Following the setup I'm trying to achieve.

- Have 2 github accounts - main and work on the same pc.
- All repos created inside the `~/work/` directory must automatically use the work name and email for commits while all repos outside this directory must use the main name and email for commits.
- Use libresecret to remember the personal-access-tokens for both accounts (main and work) to push data to github from local.
- Use personal-access-tokens instead of ssh.
- Save credentials per account as opposed to per repository (as is the case with using `useHttpPath`.

Here's what I've done.

#### Step 1: add the main github account

1. `$ git config --global user.name "Johnny"`
2. `$ git config --global user.email johnny@example.com`
3. `$ sudo apt install libsecret-1-0 libsecret-1-dev`
4. `$  cd /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/`
5. `$ sudo make`
6. `$ git config --global credential.helper /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/git-credential-libsecret`

The above allows me to push code to my main github account without typing my username and password again and again. I only need to type it once and then libsecret takes over.

`~/.gitconfig` up to this point.

```
[user]
    name = Johnny
    email = johnny@example.com

[credential]
    helper = /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/git-credential-libsecret
```

#### Step 2: add the work account

I want all repos inside the `~/work/` directory to be associated with the second github account. I make the following changes -

Global config `~/.gitconfig`

```
[user]
    name = Johnny
    email = johnny@example.com

[credential]
    helper = /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/git-credential-libsecret

[includeIf "gitdir:~/work/"]
    path = ~/work/.gitconfig
```

Work specific config `~/work/.gitconfig`

```
[user]
    name = John Doe
    email = johndoe@company.com
```

Now when I try to push my work code, I get the following error.

```
remote: Permission to work_username/mywork.git denied to main_username.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/work_username/mywork.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I solved it by splitting credential management for multiple repositories run by the same host.

7. `$ git config --global credential.github.com.useHttpPath true`

Final `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[user]
    name = Johnny
    email = johnny@example.com

[credential]
    helper = /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/git-credential-libsecret

[includeIf "gitdir:~/work/"]
    path = ~/work/.gitconfig

[credential "github.com"]
    useHttpPath = true
```

#### The Issue

The issue is, I have to setup the username and password for every new repository I create once. Post that I can use it without having to type in the password every time.

How can I let `libsecret` and `git` know to use different passwords for authentication based on directory in which the repository exists? This already happens for the commit name/email using `IncludeIf`. I want to somehow extend this to password authentication too.